# Google Sheets, how to format cell color based on day of month

Tags: google-sheets, format

I have a budget, in my budget, I have listed all my debit orders, as wll as the day of the month they should be going off.

E.g:

```
Name      | Day of month
-------------------------
Insurance |     30
Gym       |      1
```

I would like o format the color RED, when the current day of the month is <= the debit orders day of month. Other wise the cell should be GREEN.

Is this possible?

Please note: I do NOT want to format based on a specific date (e.g. 2016/01/30), only the day of the month

Comment: What did you tried? (see [ask])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use conditional formatting**

1. Paste somewhere value that equals 'the debit orders day', e.g. on cell `C1`
2. Select respective range with 'Days' (say range `B2:B`) and use Format > Condition Format > Your formula
3. and use this firmula: `= $B2 <= $C$1`
4. select colour (red)
5. Exit Conditional formatting. Paint range `B2:B` as usual in green colour.

You may also use the formula `= $B2 <= 31` (hardcode the debit orders day), but this'll give you less flexibility on editing your formats.

Comment: This did help me, I would also just like you make everyone aware that you just need to make the formula for the first row, It will apply that formula to each row using that rows cell (if that makes any sense).